# Post on Google using a Nick name

Tags: google-account, google-maps, privacy, google-play-store

On the Google Play Store when you review a app right now it says posting publicly as my full name. Also on Google Maps when you review a place you been the same thing it says posting publicly as my full name. How do I change that to my Google Nick name or something different then my real name!

Comment: The question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please checkout [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

From [Write a review on Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4346705?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) (emphasis mine)

> You can leave a public review for apps, games, and other content on the Play Store. When you review something on Google Play, the review is linked to your Google Account and is public. **You can view and edit your Google Account at [aboutme.google.com](https://aboutme.google.com)**. If you don't want a review to be public, you can delete the review.

Something similar is mentioned in [Write reviews and add ratings of places](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6230175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

If you don't want that the name of your "main" account be shown, use a **secondary** account.